# Making File Geodatabase Unlockable?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, arcreader

I have several replica File Geodatabase's on my server. I publish maps to be viewed by other departments in ArcReader. These ArcReader pmf's use the replica Geodatabase's on the server.

I need to update them from time to time, but the Geodatabase's are always locked during work hours. Usually I just update at night, but when someone needs something done right away, it's a pain to ask everyone to shut it down so I can update it.

Is there anyway to prevent the users, who are only reading the data in the Geodatabase's, from creating lock files in the Geodatabase's?

Can this be done by setting user permissions on the folder?

Can it be done with some sort of ESRI security measures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make a GeoDatabase un-lockable. The locks are there for a reason as [@Darlene pointed out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63806/115). You can though remove these locks, even if a user is accessing the database.

You can use computer management for this, a Windows Administrator tool, if you have administrator access to the GeoDatabase.

1. Open Computer Management from Administrator Tools
2. Open up either Shares, Sessions or Open Files, either will work for different reasons.
3. For shares you can temporarily remove the share, effectively blocking users from accessing the share and blocking current users of the data. At this point you should have no problem duplicating.
4. For Sessions you can close all the active sessions that are accessing the GeoDatabase. This allows you to open the GeoDatabase and manually delete the lock files. Then you can duplicate. If a user is using the data, the sessions will be restored and lock files re-created the second they access the data again. They access is every time they query or pan or do anything with there GIS program.
5. Open Files is effectively the same as sessions, but deals with files as oppose to users.

Answer (score 8):

ESRI has different types of locks.  Even if the user is just reading data they will create .lock files in the fgdb to indicate that a process is reading data.

> ArcGIS ensures data integrity by preventing multiple processes from
>   simultaneously accessing data in conflicting ways. ArcGIS keeps track
>   of processes by placing *.lock files in the file geodatabase folder
>   each time a process accesses a dataset. When the process terminates,
>   its lock files are automatically deleted.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/file_ge-516860750.htm

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/file_ge-516860750.htm

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n0000002m000000

> RD-Lock - Read Lock
>
> SR-Lock - Schema Lock
>
> WR-Lock - Write Lock
>
> ED-Lock - Edit Lock

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/27219-file-geodatabase-debugging-lock-problem-what-are-quot-rd-quot-locks